# Java - Terminate a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to terminate a thread in java without using the deprecated stop() method.
The run() method in my thread calls to another method which performs a task which can take a long period of time, and I want to be able to stop it before it returns.

My problem is that I don't want to handle this in the method which is called from run, so for instance I can't use a global boolean variable in order to terminate the thread cause i can't check it within the method.
Is there a way I can use the interrupt() method in order to achieve this goal ?

Comment: If you really get stuck, can you leave the thread orphaned: set it to terminate itself upon retuning from the 'long method', set its priority to the lowest possible, and just forget about it?  Eventually, it will die on its own, unwanted and unloved.. [sob]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you *have* to rewrite the long-running method so that it checks, for instance, some global boolean or the interrupted flag. As per assylias suggestion in the comments below, you could for instance do `while (!isInterrupted()) { ... }`.

If your long-running method is in the middle of some (well behaved) blocking call, then you will want to interrupt the thread, to make it return early from the blocking call, so that you can check the condition to see if it's time to terminate.

Comment: Why use a boolean variable instead of the standard interruption mechanism?

Comment: There can be various causes for the wakeup. (In this particular example there may not be, but I think it's bad practice to interpret interruption as "terminate immediately".) I typically interpret an interruption as "state of affairs may have changed and I might need to reevaluate some condition"

Comment: @assylias because of what aioobe said (below). You don't want to kill an important task.

Comment: I don't get your argument - IMO a long running task *should* respond to interruption (which does not necessarily mean terminate immediately). So I don't see the point of having a `while(!finish)` on top of the `while(!isInterrupted())`. I may have misunderstood your comment.

Comment: That's fine if the long-running method is not buried in an opaque library and cannot be rewritten.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe you're right. I've had situations where I've had two interleaved blocking calls, like `while (keepRunning) { blockingA(); blockingB(); }` where I wanted the thread to skip to the next blocking method upon a certain event. I interrupted the thread to break out of the current blocking call, but I didn't want it to terminate unless `keepRunning` was set to false. I'm starting to doubt that this was a sensible thing to do though. Updating my answer...

Comment: so, the bottom line is that i can't use a method like it was a black box (without adjust it with the interrupt mechanism) if i want to run it on another thread ? it reduces the modularity, isn't it ?

Comment: That's pretty much it. You can always pass a callback or an AtomicBoolean to the thread to keep the code modular.

Comment: @assylias, Interruption scares me because I don't know what will happen if the interrupt occurs while my code is calling in to a third party library.  I have not yet seen a library with explicit documentation about how it handles interrupts.  I _hope_ that any interrupted library call would throw InterruptedException, and leave everything in the same state it was in before the call--that's how I would write it--but in my business, hope does not cut it with the QA department.